# Set permissions on ApplicationPoolIdentity for adding performance counters?

Tags: .net, windows, iis-7, permissions, performancecounter

**Hi,**

I have a WCF(TCP/IIS7) application that needs to add performance counters on startup, this is a bit of my code for that :

```
category = PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Orbit5Service", "MyApp Application Service Counters", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, col);
```

The problem is that this will throw an "Requested registry access is not allowed." excetpion. I really need to add this performance counters on startup so how do I grant the ApplicationPoolIdentity the rights to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hade to change the account that runes the AppPool to a account that do have admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add *iis apppool\PoolName* to group "Performance Monitor Users"

Select the Computer Location:

[image]

And type *iis apppool\PoolName*
[image]

Or with command line:

```
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" "iis apppool\PoolName" /add
```

Answer (score -1):

Add AppPool to a group "Performance Log Users".

Alternatively add AppPool to Access Control List of the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib, set that the AppPool has Full Control ACL. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555129